# Merge landsat8 bands and convert to tiles using gdal

Tags: gdal, landsat-8

I have downloaded some landsat8 TIFF files from [Amazon](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds/c1/L8/114/027/LC08_L1TP_114027_20171116_20171116_01_RT/index.html) and there are 11 bands. Then I use 
`for BAND in {4,3,2}; do 
  gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 LC08_L1TP_114027_20171116_20171116_01_RT_B$BAND.TIF farm/$BAND-projected.tif; 
done` 
and then
`convert -combine {4,3,2}-projected.tif RGB.tif`.
The color doesn't seem right. I want to convert the RGB.tif to tiles to put it on a leaftlet map, so I use 
`gdal2tiles.py -t tile -e -a 0 -z 0-12 RGB.tif img`
 but the error is shown:
`gdal2tiles.py: error: There is no georeference - neither affine transformation (worldfile) nor GCPs. You can generate only 'raster' profile tiles.`
What should I do now to merge the TIFFs and put it on a map as tiles?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to specify what you want and more details (exact command(s) used) about what you've tried.

Comment: So what did you want? You're not being clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You used ImageMagick `convert`, which doesn't support georeferencing. Use `gdalbuildvrt -separate` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to consider using `gdal_merge.py` instead of `convert` as this will keep the projection information. For instance, once you have reprojected your images using `gdal_translate`, you could:

```
gdal_merge.py -o L8_RGB.tif *-projected.tif -separate
```

You could then use the output in `gdal2tiles.py`